# Python - Combination of powers of two to obtain target sum

Tags: python, recursion, combinations

I need to find all combinations of powers of two to obtain a target sum with a specific length of the single combination

eg

```
target_sum = 10
target_len = 3  # (number of powers of two to use)
input_list = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 8]
```

The repetition of the values 1, 2, 4 etc is variable but always `<= target_len`

The real input in production is ~10k elements, target_sum 5/50000, target_len up to 1000

another way to represent the input is `[(1, 2), (2, 3), (4, 2), (8, 1)]`  (same as `collections.Counter(input_list)`)

the solution would be:
`[(1, 1, 8), (2, 4, 4)]` or `[((1, 2), (8, 1)), ((2, 1), (4, 2))]` in the latter notation

assumptions:

- powers of 2 are contiguous (cannot be 1, 1, 2, 2, 8, ...)

This function will be called many times and must be fast, I cannot explore all the solutions using itertools.*

I have already found a solution, is fast but not elegant and I was wondering if anyone had a good idea.

(cython or c-like codes are welcome)

EDIT

the funcion used as reference is

```
def pow2_to_target_len_sum_reference(x: (list, tuple), target_sum, target_len):
    return [i for i in set(itertools.combinations(x, target_len)) if sum(i) == target_sum]
```

this is ~10k faster but ugly

```
def _make_first_guess(t, target_sum, target_len):
    guess , valid = [], []

    v, n = t
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        s = v * i
        if s > target_sum:
            break
            
        reach_sum = s == target_sum
        reach_len = i == target_len

        if reach_sum & (i < target_len):
            break
        if reach_len & (s < reach_sum):
            break
        if reach_sum and reach_len:
            valid.append((v, i))
            break

        guess.append(([(v, i)], s, i))
    return guess, valid


def _evaluate_next_guess(t, target_sum, target_len, cur_sum, cur_len):
    guess, valid = [], []

    v, n = t
    for i in range(1, n + 1):

        temp_len = cur_len + i
        temp_sum = cur_sum + (v * i)

        reach_sum = temp_sum == target_sum
        reach_len = temp_len == target_len

        if reach_sum & reach_len:
            valid.append((v, i))
            break
        elif reach_sum | reach_len:
            break
        else:
            if temp_sum > target_sum:
                break
            if temp_len > target_len:
                break

        guess.append(((v, i), temp_sum, temp_len))
    return guess, valid


def _append_guess(comb, list_prev_guess, target_sum, target_len):
    list_new_guess, ret_valid = [], []

    for cur_guess, cur_sum, cur_len in list_prev_guess:
        list_guess_to_append, list_valid = _evaluate_next_guess(comb, target_sum, target_len, cur_sum, cur_len)

        for valid in list_valid:
            ret_valid.append(cur_guess + [valid])
        for new_guess, new_sum, new_len in list_guess_to_append:
            concat_guess = cur_guess + [new_guess]
            list_new_guess.append((concat_guess, new_sum, new_len))

    return list_new_guess, ret_valid


def pow2_to_target_len_sum(li, target_sum: int, target_len: int):
    # list like [1,1,1,2,2,4,4,4,8,8,16,16,16,16]
    list_counts = list(Counter(li).items())
    rev_counts = list_counts[::-1]

    ret = []

    for i in range(len(rev_counts)):
        starting_list = rev_counts[i:]
        list_guess, valid = _make_first_guess(starting_list[0], target_sum, target_len)

        # ret += valid

        if not list_guess:
            continue

        found_solution = False
        for tup in starting_list[1:]:
            new_guess, valid_after = _append_guess(tup, list_guess, target_sum, target_len)
            if valid_after:
                found_solution = True
            valid += valid_after
            # ret += valid
            list_guess += new_guess

        if valid:
            # ret at first guess: List[Tuple[int, int]]
            # ret after first guess: List[List[Tuple[int, int]]]
            # if the right solution is found at first guess ret must be fixed
            ret += valid if found_solution else [valid]

    list_readable = []

    for solution in ret:
        nested = [[i] * j for i, j in solution[::-1]]
        list_readable.append(tuple([i for j in nested for i in j]))

    return list_readable
```

Comment: can you post the code you have tried

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could post the solution you have already discovered.

Comment: What are the constraints on the input / how does that relate to the output? It sounds like you can use any powers of 2 to generate the target sum, but you have to sum three numbers to create the target sum. So I don't really understand how the input list comes into it.

Comment: I guess, the input list limits how often you can use a certain power of 2 at max!?

Comment: I wonder, if "max_len" is an upper bound for or the exact number of powers of 2, that are valid combinations. "max_len" suggests, that it's an upper bound, but your example solution does NOT include (2,8) as a combination!

Comment: Thank you guys, I edited the problem description, I hope is clear now!

>> "I wonder, if "max_len" is an upper bound for or the exact number of powers of 2" you're right, it is the target length, I changed the variable name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to efficiently find combinations of values that sum to a given result is to iterate over the frequency range of each value, thus populating the output list a certain number of times in only a single recursive call:

```
from collections import Counter
target_sum = 10
max_len = 3
input_list = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 8]
def ajax_solution1(target_sum, max_len, input_list):
    def get_combos(d, l = 0, c = [], cl = 0):
        if l == target_sum and cl == max_len:
            yield tuple(c)
        elif d and d[0][0] + l <= target_sum:
            for i in range(1, d[0][-1]+1):
                if d[0][0]*i + l <= target_sum and cl + i <= max_len:
                    yield from get_combos(d[1:], l=l+(d[0][0]*i), c = c+([d[0][0]]*i), cl = cl+i)
            yield from get_combos(d[1:], l = l, c = c, cl= cl)
    [(_, x), *vals], r = Counter(input_list).items(), []
    for i in range(1, x+1):
        if target_sum%2 == i%2:
            if i <= max_len and i <= target_sum:
                r.extend(list(get_combos(vals, l = i, c=([1]*i), cl = i)))
    r.extend(list(get_combos(vals)))
    return r

print(ajax_solution1(target_sum, max_len, input_list))
```

Output:

```
[(1, 1, 8), (2, 4, 4)]
```

---

Timings:

The graph below illustrates the greater efficiency of the function `ajax_solution1` as opposed to both the basic `itertools` implementation for the same problem along with the OP's code. A Gist with the timing source code can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/Ajax12345/7907a628a778558ee856abc6ba264c7d).

[image]

Comment: Thank you Ajax, your code is awesome and elegant. Much more than mine. I try to get a cue from it. I posted mine in the initial post. It is a bit faster than yours but still ugly

Comment: @disable0 I updated my original code to be a bit more optimized. Based on my tests, both our solutions now have about the same average run time, particularly on large input test cases (where `len(input_list) > 7`)

Comment: thx, I fix my code, there was a bug when the solution was made of a single power of two  (eg 64 --> (32, 32))